# Possible to do an ajax get and then post that data to php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make an ajax GET request to a controller outside of my program when a button is clicked on my form and I want to use the data returned to build  "results" dynamically with PHP/HTML.

Im using the following ajax (please excuse the weird jquery format.  I have to use jQuery() instead of $() because of wordpress' no conflict mode).

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j('.button-1').click(function(){

    var distanceInput = $j('#distance-value').text().match(/[0-9]+/);
    var zipInput = $j('.location-search input').val();

    $j.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Secret' : 'secretkeyexample'
        },
        url: 'https://example.net/api/1/index.php?r=OfficeLocator/getOfficesInRange',
        data: { zip: zipInput , range: distanceInput },
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: doSomethingHere
        }
    });

})
});
```

I want to use that data in a PHP file setup like this

```
<div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="min-height:706px; height:auto">
<?php
    $results; // Store the json data here
    $i = 0;
?>
<h2 data-fontsize="35" data-lineheight="40">Search Results</h2>
<?php foreach ($results as $officeId => $officeArray) : ?>
    <?php $i++ ?>

    <div class="search-result-number"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
    <div class="search-result-city"><?php echo $officeArray['officename']; ?></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p>
        <?php echo $officeArray['addr2'] ?><br>
        <?php echo $officeArray['state'] ?><br>
        <?php echo $officeArray['phone'] ?><br>
        <?php echo $officeArray['fax'] ?><br>
    </p>
    <hr class="search-result-hr">

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Forgive me as I'm not the most familiar with AJAX but I suppose what I'm trying to do is POST the data to the PHP file from the ajax GET.  Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Look into jQuery's `deferred objects`. This should help a bit.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to make the original request in jQuery? Your PHP script could handle the request to the controller. All you'd have to do is one AJAX call to the PHP to get the final result (be it HTML or what-have-you).

Answer (score 0):

Try It because JavaScript variable Rules is `var k` not `var $k`

```
    var k = jQuery.noConflict();
    k(document).ready(function(){
       k('.button-1').click(function(){
        var distanceInput = k('#distance-value').text().match(/[0-9]+/);
        var zipInput = k('.location-search input').val(); 
        // Ajax Code Here       
        k.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://example.net/api/1/index.php?r=OfficeLocator/getOfficesInRange',
            data: { zip: zipInput , range: distanceInput},                
        });  
       // Ajax Response Here
       .done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });  
      });
    });
```

Check it Syntax [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  and [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)